# How to prevent a parent element's size from sizing child

Tags: css

If I have a container with a fixed size, is there a way to absolutely position its children in a way where the container's size doesn't affect the size of the children?

```html
<div style="background: indigo; width: 300px; height: 200px; position: relative;">
  Fixed size container
  <div style="background: darkblue; display: inline-block; position: absolute; left: 200px; top: 0px;">
    I'd like this child to overhang, not wrap.
  </div>
</div>
```

I don't want to set an explicit size on the child, and I want its measured size to not be restricted by the parent.

https://jsfiddle.net/nbilyk/2vzb1e4t/latest/

Comment: add     margin-right: -300px; to the absolute element (or any big negative value)

Answer (score 0):

> add margin-right: -300px; to the absolute element (or any big negative value) – Temani Afif

Comment: no need to add such comment, I already closed with a duplicate. If you found the answer useful you can upvote my answer in the other question where I am saying the same thing with more details